# created apache service using docker compose but unable to access the apache(httpd) over browser

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.11 # this will use the latest version of 1.11.x
    ports:
      - '80:80' #expose 80 on host and send it to container on 80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
  web: 
    image: httpd #this will use httpd latest
```

I executed above code in an AWS EC2 instance and it created two services proxy and web as expected.

I have installed docker and docker compose on Ec2 instance and 
inbound/outbound rule is "all traffic" for this instance which means port `80` is open on this instance.

However, when i try to access apache(httpd) over browser using 
url `htpp://Public Ip of EC2 Instance:80` then it does not open default page of apache and instead it shows message:

> This site can’t be reached 54.211.70.155 refused to connect. Try: Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Can you verify on the ec2 by curl http://127.0.0.1

Comment: when i performed curl , this is what get in output
curl 127.0.0.1
   "curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"

Comment: hey andzwjwp, could you please update futher on this issue

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work even on the EC2 itself, so it's not about the security groups. On a second glance - your docker-compose does something a little odd - there are 2 webservers, of those actually the nginx will be exposed on port 80, the httpd does not havy any ports exposed, so will  not be accessible at all. What are you trying to achieve with this, ultimately?